# GCP managed instance group won't scale to zero

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, gce-instance-group

I have a GCP managed instance group that I want to scale out and in between 0 and 1 instances using a cron schedule.
GCP has a [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-schedules#limitations) that says:

> Scaling schedules can only be used for MIGs that have at least one other type of autoscaling signal, such as a signal for scaling based on average CPU utilization, load balancing serving capacity, or Cloud Monitoring metrics.

So I must specify an additional autoscaling signal.
The documentation goes on to suggest a workaround:

> to scale based only on a schedule, you can set your CPU utilization target to 100%.

So I did. But then the managed group does not scale in to 0, it just stays at 1.
I've not used the `Scale-in controls`, so the only thing AFAICT that can prevent scale in is the   10 minute `Stabilization period`, which I have accounted for.

My autoscaler configuration:

```json
{
   "name":"myname",
   "target":"the/url",
   "autoscalingPolicy":{
      "minNumReplicas":0,
      "maxNumReplicas":1,
      "scalingSchedules":{
         "out":{
            "minRequiredReplicas":1,
            "schedule":"0,20,40 * * * *",
            "durationSec":300,
            "description":"scale out"
         }
      },
      "cpuUtilization":{
         "utilizationTarget":1
      }
   }
}
```

The schedule itself sets 5 minutes of scale-out to 1 instance, and then there are 10 minutes of stabilization, and then scale in to 0 should happen, but it does not.

If I use the same configuration, but only change `maxNumReplicas=2` and `minRequiredReplica=2`, the autoscaler does scale in and out at the expected times, but between 1 and 2 instances. I think this means the schedule itself is fine.

My theory is that `cpuUtilization` signal prevents scaling in to 0. Is there a way I could scale between 0 and 1 on a schedule? perhaps another signal, not `cpuUtilization`?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be better asked on serverfault as it is not a programming question. Though I find it interesting that the MIG was created with autoscaler   "minNumReplicas": "0" as it might [not be allowed](https://medium.com/@florian.perucki/google-compute-engine-auto-scaling-mrq-worker-groups-from-zero-machines-10de784ba406). Maybe using this [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/describe) to describe the MIG might reveal more information .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

The limitation that an additional autoscaling signal must be specified with scaling schedules is now gone and it is now possible to configure a schedule that would alternate between 0 and 1 instances (but see the general answer below).

**When it is possible to scale to 0 instances:**

1. min_num_replicas is set to 0.
2. Only these autoscaling signals are used: [schedules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-schedules) or [per-group Cloud Monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#per_group_metrics) (or both).

In particular it is not possible to scale to 0 when one of autoscaling signals is CPU utilization, LB utilization or [per-instance Cloud Monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#per_instance_metrics).

Comment: this has been very useful to me. Can this information be found anywhere in the GCP documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You are allowing auto scaling after CPU utilization reaches 100% (Autoscaling Policy). Because of that performance will be impacted. So you can set the policy between 60% to 90%.

Minimum number of instances (minNumReplicas) for instance groups with/without auto scaling should be 1, So Scale In at 0 is not possible.

For other signals/metrics also (HTTP Load balancing utilization, Stackdriver Monitoring Metric) Scale In at 0 is not possible.

Use Scale In controls. It helps if sudden load spikes occur.